# Can gnuplot convert my temperature data on the fly?

Tags: converters, gnuplot, temperature

I have a column of numeric data that is temperature in Fahrenheit.  How can I get gnuplot to display this on my y axis as Celsius?  Can gnuplot recalculate the values for me?  I can get plot to display the temperature nicely but only in Fahrenheit.

Comment: Yes, you take the conversion formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit and calculate the celsius values in the `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks Christoph.  For anyone else with this query, instead of plot 'temps.dat' using 1:2 I entered plot 'temps.dat' using 1:(($2-32)*.55) and my y axis and values were now all in Celsius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
plot 'temps.dat' using 1:2
```

I entered

```
plot 'temps.dat' using 1:(($2-32)*.55)
```

and my `y`-axis and values were now all in Celsius.